# Azerbaijan job - Best way to take money from the contract

Tags: income-tax, corporate-earnings

I am in the process of getting a job in Baku, and have been offered X amount, and been told to pay the taxes on it.  My question, given I'd be in Baku 183 days a year, would be how best to pay taxes; would it be to declare them locally, declare them in the UK or still be paid through my own limited company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to HM Revenue & Custom's [Double taxation treaty of UK with Azerbaijan and all its details (PDF)](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/international/azerbaijan-dtc.pdf).

Comment: Seems all a bit too convoluted. May have to live there too me thinks...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of question best answered by a professional specialist in international taxation, who knows something about Azerbaijan. The precise rules can be very complicated, and consulting a professional can save you thousands. Even little things like exactly how many days you spend in the country can make a difference. I did that when I changed countries, and their advice saved me thousands.